# Map the object using javascript and get expected structure object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to map below mentioned object...

Input object:

```
const rules = {
    public: [
      { label: 'View', value: 'View' },
      { label: 'Create', value: 'Create' },
      { label: 'Delete', value: 'Delete' },
      { label: 'Update', value: 'Update' },
      { label: 'ChangeLayout', value: 'ChangeLayout' }
    ],
    user: [
      { label: 'View', value: 'View' },
      { label: 'Create', value: 'Create' },
      { label: 'Delete', value: 'Delete' },
      { label: 'Update', value: 'Update' },
      { label: 'ChangeLayout', value: 'ChangeLayout' }
    ]
  };
```

Expected output is:

```
 const result = {
        Public: { "View": true, "Create": false, "Delete": false, "Update": false, "ChangeLayout": false },
        User: { "View": true, "Create": true, "Delete": true, "Update": true, "ChangeLayout": true }
      };
```

Actually i try some method but cant getting expected output

Thanks to advance please help anyone...

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected output ?

Comment: Where should the object keys come from, the `label` or `value` property?

Comment: what did you try so far? please add your code.

Comment: Hai Rahul Kumar above i have mentioned input object i want map to return like expect out thats also mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a single object from your array, you can use a [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation, assigning the resulting *key* name via [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

```js
const rules = [{"label":"View","value":"View"},{"label":"Create","value":"Create"},{"label":"Delete","value":"Delete"},{"label":"Update","value":"Update"}]

const keyFrom = "value"

const t0 = performance.now()
const result = rules.reduce((obj, rule) => ({
  ...obj,
  [rule[keyFrom]]: true
}), {})
const t1 = performance.now()

console.log(result)
console.log(`Operation took ${t1 - t0}ms`)
```

I wasn't sure which property should provide the key name in your final object so I made it configurable via the `keyFrom` variable.

Comment: Hi please re-review the question , i did some corrections...

Comment: @GowdhamGM I don't know why you accepted this answer. I'm not going to update it to match your ever shifting requirements so you should probably just accept [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68570226/283366) instead

Comment: @Barmar this answer also helped for my project thats why...

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use below code

```
const rules = [
      { label: 'View', value: 'View' },
      { label: 'Create', value: 'Create' },
      { label: 'Delete', value: 'Delete' },
      { label: 'Update', value: 'Update' }
    ];

    let outPut = {};
    rules.forEach(item => {
      outPut[item.value] = true;
    })

    console.log(outPut);
```

Comment: FYI, OP hasn't tagged this with [tag:typescript] so they might find the `any` confusing

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function is just returning a string, so `map()` is creating an array of strings, not an object.

The callback function should return an array containing the key and value. Then you can use `Object.fromEntries()` to turn that into the desired object.

```js
const rules = {
    public: [
      { label: 'View', value: 'View' },
      { label: 'Create', value: 'Create' },
      { label: 'Delete', value: 'Delete' },
      { label: 'Update', value: 'Update' },
      { label: 'ChangeLayout', value: 'ChangeLayout' }
    ],
    user: [
      { label: 'View', value: 'View' },
      { label: 'Create', value: 'Create' },
      { label: 'Delete', value: 'Delete' },
      { label: 'Update', value: 'Update' },
      { label: 'ChangeLayout', value: 'ChangeLayout' }
    ]
};

const test = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(rules).map(
  ([owner, rules]) => [owner, Object.fromEntries(
    rules.map(rule => [rule.value, true]))]));

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Hi please re-review the question , i did some corrections...

Comment: It's just another level of using `map` and `Object.fromEntries()`. This time it maps over `Object.entries()` since it's mapping over an object rather than an array.

Comment: Do you really need to capitalize the first letter of `public` and `user`? I'll leave that as an exercise for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript